# How do you currently track bugs in python using freely available software/websites?

Tags: python, bugs

I am starting a project using Python to track, archive, assign and manage bioinformatics bugs. This software will be able to be integrated into project management software or stand alone.

- How do you currently track bugs/assign bioinformatics bugs using freely available bioinformatics software/websites?
- What are features that you like/dislike? What are features that you would like to see in a bioinformatics bug tracker?

I am a Biology student with basic/core Python skills.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question! Unfortunately, this question is unlikely to be answered by a single best response. This type of question is probably better suited to https://www.biostars.org/

Answer (score 2):

Use IPython and activate the trace in the Python debugger as follows

```
%pdb 1
```

or

```
%pdb on
```

to turn this off `%pdb 0` or `%pdf off`

I do recommend using a formal IDE such as PyCharm or Visual Studio Code. The professional version of PyCharm is highly rated and within that use **breakpoints** . In Python3.7 there is supposed to be `breakpoint()` so you may not need an IDE, i.e. you set the breakpoint in your code using `breakpoint()`. In older versions of Python you can import this function via, `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Finally check out `PDB++` which is found [here](https://pypi.org/project/pdbpp/)

Its important to note that experienced programmers often debug by simply inserting `print()` throughout their code and don't bother with an IDE